# How to access a deep level in an object with a string parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops, object

I have a sample object like this:

```
const test1 = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 2
    }
  }
}
```

When I pass a parameter like: 'a', 'a.b' or 'a.b.c'. How can access the right level of the object in an effective way?

I tried to loop through it but couldn't figure out a method to do it properly.

Any ideas? Thanks,

```js
const test1 = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 2
    }
  }
}

const item1 = 'a.b'
const item2 = 'a.b.c'

console.log(test1[item1]) // should be { c: 2 }
console.log(test1[item2]) // should be 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: Thanks @Nit for your reference.

Comment: Simply, what you want is if you have 'a.b.c' you need to show {c: 2}. Am I correct?

Comment: It's true. Do you have a better method than the one from Nit?

Comment: I have a solution for your problem. But this question is already closed. how can I give you the code?

Comment: @DushanRandika you can contribute the duplication above. I will able to see it.